Text in math environment in algorithm2e has different typography when placed inside a for loop
The following MWE:
% Created 2016-07-04 Mon 15:02
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}



\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    $D_b^{\text{max}}$

    \For{${D_b^{\text{max}}}$}
    {
    }
  \end{algorithm}



\end{document}

results in:

As you can see, the text max has two different typography. In the for loop instruction, it is italicized while I want that it remains like in line 1 of the algorithm.
I tried to put \displaystyle but it did not change. Removing command \text in line two doesn't work either.

The command \text is for textual insertions in formulas, respecting the font that's current outside the formula.
Text inside \For and the other similar commands of algorithm2e is typeset in italics.
Anyway, your “max” is not a textual insertion and should always be typed in as \mathrm{max} (or, with a slight abuse, \max).
Here I use both, just to show that the result is the same, but \mathrm{max} is conceptually better (and applies to other similar abbreviations in formulas).
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    $D_b^{\mathrm{max}}$

    \For{${D_b^{\max}}$}
    {
    }
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}


